# Can I search where I have set a global or environment variable in postman?

Tags: postman

I have many collections with 10+ requests in them and have set many global and environment variables in all these requests. Now, if I don't remember where I have set a specific variable and in what requests I am reading this variable's value, I have to manually look through all these requests to find it.

I am not aware if postman already has a search option for this functionality. Please let me know if this option is already available.

If not, then I guess it would good to have a search option that would show me where I have set a variable and in what requests I am reading this variable's value.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it in app, but you can export your collection and search the export file for your var names.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I did some more searching on this, and found out a feature request in github for this - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2016.

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of the Postman App there is a "Find and Replace" tab:
[image: bottom bar of Postman App with "Find and Replace" tab]

(or hit Ctrl+Shift+F)

If you have an environment variable "my-env-var" you can enter in the search bar:

- read usage: `{{my-env-var}}` or `pm.environment.get("my-env-var"`
- write usage: `pm.environment.set("my-env-var"`

The results tab "Collections" will list all occurences in your collections.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do it.

For now you can use search only in a specific request:

[image]

Hope this feature will be implemented soon.